# How can speed at a given position be estimated from a bunch of average speed measures at different positions?

Tags: speed

I have loose measures of average speed in different positions (speed is in the x axis given particularities of my own problem)

[image]

How can I estimate a fitting curve for 'instantaneous speed at each position' vs. 'position' ?

I guess the first step is to fit an average speed curve. 
What then?
My plot shows that the average speed around 1000m changes from about 1.01m/s to 1.05m/s, which means that instantaneous speed at that region must have been considerably higher to compensate for the 0-800m region moving slowly.

Comment: perhaps this would be more fitting for [math.se]?

Comment: You need to give more context. What is this speed and position of? What is the "average speed" here?

Comment: I think if you define "center of mass" for your system, and assign average speed to it, you will find "speed at a given position" at any time. Or maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @Luyw Hm, you may be right. I might try there

Comment: @AaronStevens It's a quite specific petrophysics problem, but for the discussion at hand, you could think of position being meters away from the start line at an athletics track and speed is the average speed as measured by referees at given positions along the track. Let's say the referees have stopwatches and therefore they can measure average speed from the start line when an athlete passes by then. But they can't calculate the actual speed at that position, only the average speed since the start. With that at hand, I understand it is possible to estimate a curve for speed at each position.

Comment: @Paradoxy If I understand what you said, you mean a curve fitting the data? This is not enough as this would only give me a better "average speed for each position X position" function. From that, I want to estimate "instantaneous speed at each position" if that is a good way to describe, as I tried to better explain in my latter comment.

Comment: What is average speed here? To determine average speed you need to specify a time interval and a displacement. Is this time interval the time from the start to the time to observe the athlete at position $X$?

Comment: @AaronStevens That´s precisely right. Displacement is the distance from the referee to the start line and the time interval is the time elapsed since the athlete left from the start line.
I don't have the time values data, though. It's as if the referees, based on their stopwatches, calculated and provided me with their measured average speed.
Another piece of information is that the fitting curves, both the average speed curve (the curve that fits the data ) and the "instanteneous" speed at each given position (that I'm trying to derive) should start on the origin (0,0).

Comment: Oh I see. However,I am afraid it's not possible to answer your question with given data,because there is not such unique instantaneous velocity at every position.For example, let's say that average of something is $10$.So what's its parts? maybe $10+10$. or maybe $15+5$ or anything else.Average speed is not an exception.Because after all, average speed is nothing but summation of different instantaneus velocity at different times divided by total time. There are infinite right choices in your case. The easiest one is to assume that between every two point average and instantaneus speed is same

Comment: @Paradoxy Yes, for a particular average velocity point there are infinite solutions. But if I have many average velocity points and first fit an average velocity function, then I think it is possible to derive an instantaneous velocity function from that average velocity function.

Answer (score 0):

In general the average speed for movement in 1D is calculated by
$$v_{\text {avg}}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}$$
where the object in question is at position $x_1$ at time $t_1$ and at position $x_2$ at time $t_2$. If we are only given the average speed and one of either $x_1$ or $x_2$ then we can't do anything to determine the other variables. This is probably where your issue is.

However, you have stated in the comments that the time intervals and displacements for the average speeds are calculated relative to the same position and time. Therefore, we know what $x_1$ and $t_1$ are. Your data points then tell us $(v_{\text{avg}},x_2$, and all we don't know is $t_2$. We can use the definition of average speed to determine $t_2$:
$$t_2=\frac{x_2-x_1}{v_{\text{avg}}}+t_1$$

Therefore, you can use your data to get $(x_2,t_2)$ points, which you can then use usual methods to determine the instantaneous velocity as a function of $t_2$.

Answer (score 0):

We normally write average speed as integral of instantaneus speed with respect to the time divided by total time interval. However, it's better to  write it with respect to position in discrete form here i.e:
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i}\Delta x_i}\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i=\frac{1}{X}\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i~~(1)$$
$\Delta x_i$ Denotes the position interval where instantaneus velocity $v(x_i)$ remains the same. If you had a continuous data, I'd have used integral and $d x$ instead of $\Delta x_i$. Equation $(1)$ gives:
$$Xv_{avg}=\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i ~ ~(2)$$
We have many $v_{avg}$ at different positions. $X$ is known from graph too (it's just the total distance from orgin to the arbitrary point). is it possible to find $v(x_i)$  then? Probably! It will depends on linearity of $v(x_i)$.
Let's do it for 2 point:
$$X_2v_{2avg}-X_1v_{1avg}=\sum_{j}v(x_j)\Delta x_j-\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i ~ ~(3)$$
Left side is known. We can also expand the right side such that we get:
$$X_2v_{2avg}-X_1v_{1avg}=\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i-\sum_{i}v(x_i)\Delta x_i~+~...~+v(x_{n-1})\Delta x_{n-1}+v(x_n)\Delta x_n ~ ~(4)$$
Let's say that $\Delta x_i$ is the same for all instantaneus velocities (linearity) and we can assume *something*  for its value. The fewer data you have, the bigger $\Delta x_i$ should be. In the case of 2 points, we can always assume $\Delta x_i$ such that equation $4$ reduces to 
$$\frac{X_2v_{2avg}-X_1v_{1avg}}{\Delta x}=v(x_n) ~ ~(5)$$
This will give us an instanteus velocity at a given position. This instanteus velocity is the same for all points in $\Delta x$. Thus if you are looking for a "real" instanteus velocity, you have to assume $\Delta x_i$ as small as possible.In your  case where we have a lot of data, one should use equation 4, without reduction. After all, you can write it between any two arbitrary points, So for every unknown parameter on the right side, there is an independent equation hopefully. (i.e you can assume a small value for $\Delta x_i$ such that many terms for instantaneus velocity at different positions emerge in the right side, you can find them all with other equations)

Note that the equation $(1)$ is like
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}v(t)dt~~~or~~~~v_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{i}v(t_i)\Delta t_i$$
And of course
$$v_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}v(t)dt=\frac{X}{T}$$